# AngularJS Work in directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

While working with two directives, there was a need to clear the value in Directive A using the button located in Directive B. But if you use the tools usually JQuery for working with the DOM, then the following error appears, the value in Directive A is reset, but only in the DOM.
How is it better to clean out an `<input type='text' ng-model='product.barcodeId'/>` Directive A using a button located in Directive B?

Directive A:

```
myApp.directive('productController', function () {
    return {
        controller: 'productController',
        controllerAs: 'product',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        },
        scope: { model: '@' },
        templateUrl: '/app/views/product.html'

    }
});
myApp.controller('productController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', productController]);

function productController($scope, $rootScope) {

    var viewModel = this;

    viewModel.rootScope = $rootScope;


    viewModel.square = function () {

        viewModel.rootScope.GlobalBarcodeId = viewModel.barcodeId;

        viewModel.result = viewModel.barcodeId * 2;
    }

}
```

Directive B:

```
myApp.directive('itemController', function () {
    return {
        controller: 'itemController',
        controllerAs: 'item',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        },
        scope: { model: '@' },
        templateUrl: '/app/views/item.html'

    }
});
myApp.controller('itemController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', itemController]);

function itemController($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {

    var viewModel = this;

    viewModel.rootScope = $rootScope;

    viewModel.timeout = $timeout;

}

itemController.prototype.clear = function () {

    var viewModel = this;

    viewModel.rootScope.GlobalBarcodeId = {};

    $('[type=number]').val('');

}
```

View A:

```
<div ng-controller="productController">
    <div>
        <input ng-model="product.barcodeId" type="number" />
        <input ng-click="product.square()" type="submit"/>
        <h1>Result: {{product.result}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

View B:

```
<div ng-controller="itemController">
    <input type="button" ng-click="item.clear()" value="Clear" />
    <br />
</div>
```

View result:

```
<item-controller></item-controller>
<product-controller></product-controller>
```

I understand that my mistake is that I assign rootScope.GlobalBarcodeId, the scope value and clear in directive B, only the value of rootScope, and when cleaning just a text field, the value of viewModel.barcodeId (directive A) remains the same.
How do I clear the value of product.barcodeId (controller A) from (controllera B)?

I tried the following. Did not help:

```
itemController.prototype.clear = function () {

    var viewModel = this;

    viewModel.timeout(function () {

        viewModel.rootScope.GlobalBarcodeId = {};

        $('[type=number]').val('');

    }, 1);
}
```

> your function is $timeout call $rootScope.$apply()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to show you another way to handle it, but before starting to check the codes Read about **models**.

In this sample we have two controllers and for each of them have a directive `heroA` & `heroB`, for having model between controllers we should use `app.run` for binding with `$rootScope` to using in `views`, `directives` for each controller.

This model is unique and every changes from anywhere `views`, `directives` make it change in the source *(controller)*

This can helps you to get better result and you will be sure get **one** result without any changing in the model because your model already passing between two or more directives and will return to controller again.

> By using models in your app you figure out, using **jQuery** is *unnecessary* at all in **Angularjs**

**Eventually this is a simple sample to show how models works:**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.model = {
    barcodeId: 1, //you can set this value by dynamic way
    result: null
  }
});

app.controller("ctrlA", function($scope) {})

app.directive("heroA", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      model: "="
    },
    template: "<input ng-model='model.barcodeId' type='number' /><button ng-click='getModel()'>getModel</button>",
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.getModel = function() {
        scope.model.result = scope.model.barcodeId
      }
    }
  }
})

///

app.controller("ctrlB", function($scope) {})

app.directive("heroB", function($rootScope) {
  return {
    scope: {
      model: "="
    },
    template: "<button ng-click='clear()'>Clear</button>",
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.clear = function() {
        $rootScope.model.barcodeId = null;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="ctrlA">
        <h1>
            Directive A
        </h1>
        <hero-a model="model"></hero-a>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="ctrlB">
        <h1>
            Directive B
        </h1>
        <hero-b model="model"></hero-b>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1>Result after submit</h1>
        {{model.result}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case, there is a directive A with controller A, there is a text field in their representation (ng-model = 'ctrlA.barcodeId') And there is a directive B with controller B in which there is a button with which I want to clean out the text field from directive A located in the controller A. I tried your example, but I did not understand how to use your variable model in the view. I can pass the value from ng-model = ctrlA.barcodeId to it and then get this variable in ctrlB, but because in ctrlA I assign it a value from the ng-model it is saved every time, for example, simply text form

Comment: update answer according to last comment and also i used `model` for it, check out the code please

Comment: barcodeId at you static will be equal to one and if you reset the value of model, then the next step you will get the value one. In your directive A there is not enough button that gets the value from the ng-model. Then you will understand everything clearly. We set the value in heroA and call a certain function (using ng-click) the scope of A. Then we zero rootscope and when we call A, we get not an empty value, but one

Comment: Actually you can changes my codes in your project this is just a help to understand what you have to do.

Comment: I tried what you demonstrated before creating a question. My problem is not so trivial. so I want you to understand what the task is and what you demonstrated is not applicable to my question

Comment: That because your codes is not clear (because of that your question get negative point from others), and i try to help you anyway. however let talk about last version of my codes to get best result.

Comment: I updated the question. I hope you understand that I want to explain to you and can help me :]

Answer (score 1):

> **For learning** when you try to use a framework whatever it is, you have to use framework tools to **apply** your target.
>
> **For this case** already you using **Angularjs** framework making 2 directives which has some events to making change in each-other (however), i see in your directive you using **jQuery** too, to making input empty! exactly this is what i mean.

When you using `jQuery` in `Angular` you need to `$apply` it , this should happen because angular need to know what happens there *(directive)*

**So**

*after `jQuery` event set*

```
scope.$apply();
```

Actually you can do it in **directive link** too.

> **Note**: there is more ways to handle your situation

Comment: what is the best way to solve my problem? Could you demonstrate?

Comment: I use timeout, but the data in the ng-model is still preserved